# Saving gamer Ryan!

Tags: crossword-clues

Ryan is an avid gamer. He has played all sorts of games ranging from consoles like Xbox, PlayStation, Nintendo, etc. to PC games to mobile games. One day, it was raining heavily outside and (as always) Ryan was on his PC, playing a game. Suddenly, his house was struck by lightning. As his PC was connected to the mains power supply, the lightning travelled down through the wires and shocked him - but he didn't die; he just vanished into thin air! Oh no! Where did he go?! Looks like he entered into the game he was playing (as weird as it sounds, it did happen).

Ryan needs to be saved. He has appeared in front of a castle with 100 floors. Each floor contains a boss. Ryan has to defeat each boss and proceed to the next floor. If he defeats the final boss on the 100<sup>th</sup> floor, he wins and can escape the game. But if he dies in-game, he dies physically. There is a pamphlet with him. Inside the pamphlet is a crossword:

> [image]
>
> (1) 01010101
> (2) A music composition
> (3) A city in China
> (4) Spot on the skin
> (5) A tool used by surgeons
> (6) A dog breed

Solve the crossword and help Ryan win the game. Your other task is to **identify the name of the game**.

Additional points to those:

> who can relate the crossword with the name of the game.

Comment: @Deusovi -- Yea, I was gonna say, these aren't cryptic clues.

Comment: [cryptic-crosswords] has a specific meaning (with each clue decomposing into "definition" and "wordplay"). I've retagged it as [crossword-clues], since I think that's closer to your intention - if that's not right, feel free to fix it (and/or let me know)!

Comment: @Deusovi Thanks for the tip. I am new to this community and needs some time with the tags. Happy puzzling :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crossword solutions:

> BINARY
>  SONATA
>  SHENZHEN (or something, I took the first which has 3rd letter E :)
>  FRECKLE
>  SCALPEL
>  TERRIER
>
>  Highlighted cells spell [Isekai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isekai) which revolves around a normal person from Earth being transported to, reborn or otherwise trapped in a parallel universe or fantasy world.

I think the name of the game is

> [Age of Aincrad](https://age-of-aincrad.gamepedia.com/Age_of_Aincrad:_Content_Page), a game based on the anime Sword Art Online. It has [100 floors with bosses](https://age-of-aincrad.gamepedia.com/Floors)

Comment: Shucks, got sniped

Comment: That was lightening fast ;) Ok, proceed to help Ryan!!!